# Google Documents List API version 3.0

Tags: java, google-api

I'be seen that gdata Google Documents List API version 3.0 is been depreciated for a while  now? However, I am still wondering whether somebody is able to use it successfully. I am trying to get the document list and keep getting a Parsing error. Also tried the sample app with the same results. Wondering whether the api is not usable anymore?

```
xception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: Unrecognized content type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2136)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2098)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1136)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:645)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)
at com.tst.preprocessing.external.google.GetDocumentsTest.main(GetDocumentsTest.java:51)
```

Thanks.